# PHP convert time to decimal with/without colon

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a pay calculator for work, and they pay us to the minute using decimal time. I.e. **8.5 units instead of 8:30**.

Due to the number of people of who'll be using this I'm trying to account for colon and non-colon use, as well as 3 and 4 digits (*we work in 24 hour time, so some people will use 230 instead of 02:30.*)

My code I've got thus far is:

```
function timeValidation($time) {
    $time = strpos($time, ':');

    if( $time == true ) {
        $time = explode(':', $time);
        $time = $time[0].$time[1];
    }

    if( strlen($time) <= 3 ) {
        $time = '0'.$time;
    }

    return $time;
}

echo $start = timeValidation($start);
```

When I  run it separately outside of the function it works as expected, but once it's in the function I'm not getting the output I'd expect. I'm not sure if this is due to my function being wrong or the logic inside the function though.

I have searched for questions that might help me, but I couldn't seem to find anything. I'm more than happy for someone to point me to a similar question if it's out there.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First line in function overwrite your original time `$time = strpos($time, ':');`

Comment: Could you not just remove the colon as the first thing you do `str_replace(':', '', $string);`and then from that point you'll only have to work with one format?

Comment: @BrainFooLong Thanks for that. I missed it from staring at it for so long.

Comment: @Pigeon I suppose I could. It's been a few years since I've coded something that's getting complex, so it's taking a bit to get my hand back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the problem, but it looks like you're over complicating it for yourself.

```
function standardiseTimeFormat($time) {
    $time = str_replace(':', '', $time);
    if (strlen($time) <= 3) {
        $time = '0' . $time;
    }

    return $time;
}
```

So if I pass through:

```
$time_one = '18:30';
$time_two = '3:30';
$time_three = '1830';
$time_four = '330';
```

I get the following results:

> 1830
>   0330
>   1830
>   0330

**Edit:** Just a little clean up:

```
function standardiseTimeFormat($time) {
    $time = str_replace(':', '', $time);
    return str_pad($time, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

And just for *funsies* if you wanted a one liner..

```
function standardiseTimeFormat($time) {
    return str_pad(str_replace(':', '', $time), 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: Could simplify with `return sprintf('%04d', $time);` instead of the `if <= 3`

Comment: No, it would appear you've understood it perfectly. And I agree, this is much tidier. I suppose I could add my str_split to this too, to make life easier.

Comment: Ah cool, glad I could help then @BigJazzz, did update it with a little variation depending on which you prefer :p

Comment: Lol! I like you. You use "funsies". :P What's the str_pad do though?

Comment: Ohhhh... Pad the string?

Comment: @Pigeon So I broke it again. If I can't get it working I'll post a new question. :P

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting your `$time` variable inside the function when you're trying to determine whether it has a colon or not. Try this instead:

```
$start = '18:30';

function timeValidation($time) {
    $isTime = strpos($time, ':');
    if( $isTime == true ) {
        $time = explode(':', $time);
        $time = $time[0].$time[1];
    }
    if( strlen($time) <= 3 ) {
        $time = '0'.$time;
    }

    return $time;
}
echo $start = timeValidation($start);
```

---

Output:

> 1830

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for that. Set of fresh eyes is a wonderful thing.